# Image in FormData to Node Server then to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, busboy

I have an angular 2 application that is sending an image wrapped inside a FormData object to my node server.

I can receive the image on the server and write it to a file, then redownload it:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {


     if(mimetype == "image/png"){
        var saveTo = path.join('/home/ec2-user/bonappetite/tmp', path.basename(filename) + ".png");
     } else if(mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
        var saveTo = path.join('/home/ec2-user/bonappetite/tmp', path.basename(filename) + ".jpg");
     } else {
         var saveTo = path.join('/home/ec2-user/bonappetite/tmp', path.basename(filename));
      }
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));

});

busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log("url retrieved");
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
    res.end(savedUrl);
});
return req.pipe(busboy);
```

What I am trying to do is take the image inside the FormData and upload it to my S3 bucket. I am able to upload data myself, but I cant seem to upload the image that I have saved from the post request

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./aws_config.json');
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'xxxx'} } );



params = {Key: filename, Body: file};
s3Bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {

if (err) {

    console.log(err)

} else {
    var urlParams = {Bucket: 'xxxx', Key: filename};
    s3Bucket.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function(err, url){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status( err.status || 500 );
                res.send( error );
            }else {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                url = url;
                res.send({"url":url});
            }
    })

}
});
```

How can I take the file that I have just uploaded to my server and stream it to S3?

Do i even need to save the file to disk prior to sending it to s3?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Found Solution to this problem without having to save the file.

Rather than using putObject, use upload.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./aws_config.json');
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'xxxx'} } );



params = {Key: filename, Body: file};
s3Bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {

if (err) {

    console.log(err)

} else {
    var urlParams = {Bucket: 'xxxx', Key: filename};
    s3Bucket.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function(err, url){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status( err.status || 500 );
                res.send( error );
            }else {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                url = url;
                res.send({"url":url});
            }
    })

}
});
```